# is it possible to tweak global Date function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to tweak the global `Date` function by preserving all functionality of `Date` but add some parameter checking inside the constructor

because I want to throw an error when calling `Date` function like this `new Date('2021-01-01')`, which will return `Invalid Date` in safari.

```js
(function () {
  let OldDate = window.Date;
  window.Date = class Date extends (
    OldDate
  ) {
    constructor(...args) {
      if (/\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d/.test(args[0])) {
        throw Error('wrong date format');
      }
      super(...args);
    }
  };
})();
```

but this approach has a pitfall, I can't call `Date` without `new` keyword

```js
// before override
new Date('2021/02/01'); // OK
Date('2021/02/01'); // OK

// after override
new Date('2021/02/01'); // OK
Date('2021/02/01'); // Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Date cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

How do I fix it?

the motivation of tweaking the global `Date` function

most newbies will tend to call `Date` function with a format like `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`, this works inside his development environment (latest version of Chrome), and he doesn't konw this won't work on safari until he tests his project on safari, so I have to tell him to change the Date format string he uses every time he falls into this problem.

Writing a code style guide won't always work, a newbie is a newbie because he always forgets things, so I have to tell him to read the style guide document again.

Instead, I want to throw an error every time the newbie use `Date` with the wrong date string format

```
new Date('2021-01-02') // Error: 'YYYY-MM-DD is wrong format', try use 'YYYY/MM/DD'
```

Comment: "*I'm trying to rewrite the global*" don't do it! "*but this approach doesn't work well, because now all Date's static methods are missing*" take a guess why CHANGING A GLOBAL OBJECT might be a bad idea.

Comment: "*but this approach doesn't work well*" - it's not just the static methods, not even `new Date()` works any longer.

Comment: @VLAZ I know how bad is the idea of "CHANGE A GLOBAL OBJECT", I am just thing about the possibility, as a technical discussion, I've updated my question.

Comment: @Littlee, what do you mean `call Date without new keyword`? You want to call a static member of `Date`? You gave an example `new Date('2021-01-01')`. So you want to call the instance members and static members of `Date`?

Comment: @Wenbo I want to make `new Date('2021/02/01')` and `Date('2021/02/01')` are both valid expressions

Comment: Have a read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because you're definitely focusing on the Y here. How about *instead of* trying to break anything that uses the global `Date`, you find a way to work with it? You can just do `new Date(2020, 0, 1)` to initialise the object. Since you seem to already have a known format coming in, it's trivial to just convert it to the components. There are also date libraries that can handle this. No need to overwrite global objects.

Comment: @VLAZ you have a point, I can certainly replace all `new Date()` code to `dayjs()` or something with regular expression, but I have updated my question to explain my whole motivation, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

No matter why you want to override Date. My solution is

```
var originalDate = Date; // backup

function _date(str) {
    // your implementation here
    if (/\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d/.test(str)) {
        throw Error('wrong date format');
    }
    return new originalDate(str);
}

window.Date = _date; // override

Object.assign(Date.prototype, originalDate.prototype); // I suppose you still want to have properties of the original Date.
```